# A quick way to repeatedly enter a variable name in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I was just typing in this sort of code for Nth time:

```
menu.add_item(spamspamspam, "spamspamspam");
```

And I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do it.

I'd like a behavior similar to yasnippet's mirrors, except
I don't want to create a snippet: the argument order varies from
project to project and from language to language.

The only thing that's constant is the variable name that needs to be
repeated several times on the same line.

I'd like to type in

```
menu.add_item($,"")
```

and with the point between the quotes, call the shortcut and start typing,
and finally exit with <kbd>C-e</kbd>.

This seems advantageous to me, since there's zero extra cursor movement.
I have an idea of how to do this, but I'm wondering if it's already done,
or if something better/faster can be done.

### UPD The yasnippet way after all.

Thanks to thisirs for the answer. This is indeed the `yasnippet` code I had initially in mind:

```
(defun yas-one-line ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "$")
  (let ((snippet 
         (replace-regexp-in-string 
          "\\$" "$1"
          (substring-no-properties
           (delete-and-extract-region
            (line-beginning-position)
            (line-end-position))))))
    (yas/expand-snippet snippet)))
```

But I'm still hoping to see something better/faster.

Answer (score 3):

`yasnippet` can actually be used to create a snippet on-the-fly:

```
(defun yas-one-line ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((snippet (delete-and-extract-region
                  (line-beginning-position)
                  (line-end-position))))
    (yas-expand-snippet snippet)))
```

Now just type:

```
menu.add_item($1,"$1")
```

and call `yas-one-line`. The above snippet is expanded by yasnippet!

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
(defvar sm-push-id-last nil)
(defun sm-push-id ()
  (interactive)
  (if (not sm-push-id-last)
      (setq sm-push-id-last (point))
    (text-clone-create sm-push-id-last sm-push-id-last
                       t "\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)*")
    (setq sm-push-id-last nil)))
```

after which you can do `M-x sm-push-id RET , SPC M-x sm-push-id RET toto` and that will insert `toto, toto`.  Obviously, this would make more sense if you bind `sm-push-id` to a convenient key-combo.  Also this only works to insert a duplicate pair of identifiers.  If you need to insert something else, you'll have to adjust the regexp.  Using too lax a regexp means that the clones will tend to overgrow their intended use, so they may become annoying (e.g. you type `foo")` and not only `foo` but also `")` gets mirrored on the previous copy).

Comment: Thanks for showing `text-clone-create`. It's not however 100% compatible with `auto-complete`.

Answer (score 1):

Record a macro. Hit `F3` (or possibly `C-x (`, it depends) to begin recording. Type whatever you want and run whatever commands you need, then hit `F4` (or `C-x )`) to finish. Then hit `F4` again the next time you want to run the macro. See chapter 17 of the Emacs manual for more information (`C-h i` opens the info browser, the Emacs manual is right at the top of the list).

So, for example, you could type the beginning of the line:

`menu.add_item(spamspamspam`

Then, with point at the end of that line, record this macro:

`F3 C-SPC C-left M-w C-e , SPC " C-y " ) ; RET F4`

This copies the last word on the line and pastes it back in, but inside of the quotes.

Comment: My impression is that you haven't tried `yasnippet`. It allows for much more than what a simple keyboard macro can do. For instance, I can couple it with autocompete, or use the visual feedback when I haven't yet decided how I want to name the variable.

Comment: Yes, but you said that you don't want to use yasnippet :)

Comment: I said like `yasnippet`. For instance `iedit` does something similar for editing once the code is already there.

Comment: I've counted the overhead keys for your solution: it's more than 10.
Whereas what I propose sets me back 3 keys:
`$` and two more for the shortcut to start recording.

Comment: Yep, there are some other alternatives. I occasionally use multiple cursors mode (https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el).